# Problems with nginx ingress and SSO redirection

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, cors, single-sign-on, kubernetes-ingress

in my application:

front (angular) is runing in an nginx server https://project-dev

back (springboot) is runing in a tomcat server https://project-back-dev

and i want to connect in SSO

the cors between back and front is configured in ingress (cloud)

I have 3 problems:

**The first one:** when i try to use SSO to logon i have a CORS error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ssoforms.dev/saml2sso?SAMLRequest=nVL…' (redirected from 'https://project-dev/api/user/login') from origin 'https://project-dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight  request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

**the second one:**

I have many redirections from front to back using /api (for exemple /api/user.  /api/login /api/test) how can i define only on rule in ingress to not list all the redirections from front to back ?

I tried to put only /api* but it doesn't work

**the Third one: **
how to add a rule for websocket in ingress ?

i have this web socket wss://project-dev/websocket from the front that should call my back

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.